# Cómo parar Samba de emitir los mensajes logs?

Tags: vps, cloud, samba

Dispongo de un servidor VPS Cloud y me estoy dando cuenta que me está generando excesivos logs por lo que termina bloqueándome los inodes del sistema linux y ya no puedo hacer algunas cosas, entre ellas por ejemplo acceder al webmail. 
Alguna sugerencia. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido esta información para poder comprobar cómo obtener información de samba en mi sistema:

Comprobar con los comandos top y free por SSH, o estos otros:

cat /proc/meminfo -> para ver el total de swap y el swap libre
cat /proc/swaps -> para ver cual de los dispositivos swap están siendo usados
swapon -s -> par ver los dispositivos swap y tamaños (donde swap está insatlado)
wmstat -> para ver las estadísticas de memoria virtual actuales

Aunque todavía me queda saber cómo bloquear dichos mensajes, es un comienzo.